# glGetUniformLocation Returns Huge Number

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Hey all my shaders both compile and link correctly... they were working before and I was working on my program over awhile not touching the vert/frag shader at all and now the glGetUniformLocation returns huge numbers when trying to get their locations.

I use it on these three variables:

```
m_sw      = glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "m_sw" );
m_sh      = glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "m_sh" );
m_grabLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "grabTexture");
```

m_sw gets the value 21692416
m_sh gets the value 21757952
m_grabLoc gets the value 21626880

all three variables have the type GLint as returned by glGetUniformLocation.

Note: that I also use it on uniforms that ARE NOT present and it correctly returns -1 so im so confused!

My vert shader looks as follows

```
#version 120

varying vec2    texCoord;

void main(void)
{   
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    texCoord    = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
}
```

My frag shader is as follows

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D grabTexture;
uniform float m_sh;
uniform float m_sw;

varying vec2        texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    vec4  col   = texture2D (grabTexture, texCoord.st);

    //left
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s-m_sw,texCoord.t));
    //right
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s+m_sw,texCoord.t));
    //below
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s,texCoord.t-m_sh));
    //top
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s,texCoord.t+m_sh));
    //the corners of the pixels
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s+m_sw,texCoord.t+m_sh));
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s-m_sw,texCoord.t+m_sh));
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s+m_sw,texCoord.t-m_sh));
    col += texture2D (grabTexture, vec2(texCoord.s-m_sw,texCoord.t-m_sh));

    gl_FragColor = col *  0.111111f;
}
```

it is a full screen anti alias-er btw.

Just wondering if anyone else has had this problem or knows a fix?

EDIT: I think its worth metnioning if i change gl_FragColor to 
    gl_FragColour = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
if indeed makes the screen read (as expected) so the shader is definitely working! :(

Comment: I can't tell you why you're getting those values, but it's interesting to note that in hex they are 0x14A0000, 0x14B0000, and 0x14C0000.

Comment: Unless you have issues in using the returned location later, is there a reason to think this is a problem ?

Comment: What type is `m_sw`, etc?

Comment: @user1118321 that is weird!

Comment: @prabindh I am having issues though, that is the thing. Before (when the shader was working) it was returning sensible figures and...not to mention... it was working :(

Comment: @Vallentin they are all GLint, which is the return type of glGetUniformLocation

Comment: Could you please show the rest of your code, it might be something else causing it, and we can't see what else could be causing it with that small amount of code.

Comment: `gl_FragColour` with a `u`?

Comment: @genpfault sorry that was my typing it out on here (being from the UK) no I put gl_FragColor in my actual shader

Comment: @Vallentin https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fzcgd4dlcsbl5ol/S5TkZkEikX is a copy and paste of the functions that create the shader and use it

Comment: Could this be something to do with having an intel graphics card? 
Using endian ording etc. as @user1118321 pointed out what they were in hex... if they were swapped would it equal 0,1,2 etc.? Ill have a check now

Comment: Okay after having that thought (I didnt get to convert from big to little endian) but I can confirm that these big numbers do actually work...
I ended up setting m_sw to 1.0f when calling the shader and then changing gl_FragColor to glFragColor = vec4(m_sw,0,0,0); and it was red as expected!!! so my shader has stopped working somehow
Sorry for the bogus post but this was a very confusing bug! :(

Comment: There is no requirement that the values have to start at zero. One of the only guarantees that GLSL makes regarding assigned uniform locations is that uniform arrays will be assigned sequential locations for each element. Assuming anything in addition to this is a recipe for disaster. By the way, you might find some sample code I listed in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894839/opengl-uniform-array-of-structures/19918602#19918602) helpful in this situation, it will run through all of the ***active*** uniforms in your GLSL program and print detailed information for each.